# Access value in the class of list without loop(nested class)?

Tags: c#, json, class, loops, nested

i would like to ask is it possible for me to direct access the value in a nested list class without looping ?
The below code is work, but i want to simplify it and can direct access the value. Thank youvery much.

```
RootObject myjsondata = new RootObject();

RootObject jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(html);

if(jarray.items.Count>0)
{
    foreach (var a in jarray.items) 
    {
        string b = a.snippet.title;
    }
}

public class Snippet
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what do you expect to happen if you don't loop?

Comment: Do you mean this: `jarray[2].items[3].snippet.title`